# ExpressJs route redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I have a widget for user to get information regarding books. The UX of the widget changes according to the fact that the user is logged in or not. Now I have a route for logged-in user(say, /user/getBookInfo) to get the book information(which includes sending sms n email logic). For users who are not logged-in I have created a different route(say, /public/getBookInfo), which includes some additional processing too. However retrieving the book information, sms and email logic etc is already present in '/user/getBookInfo'. I don't want to duplicate this function. 
One option is call res.redirect('/user/getBookInfo') from /public/getBookInfo . However I want to avoid the redirect in this way.
So My question is How can I reuse this logic in /public/getBookInfo without using redirect??

Comment: Why not you use role based authentication? For logged in users you can have all options available and for anonymous users you can only show certain basic options. Having two different routes would not be so good.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way in a Node.js application is to make a separate module, and put the common logic there. Then you can `require` the module in both routing files.

Comment: The function also contains mongoose logic. Let me try it tho.

Comment: If you add some code to the question, we could offer some better suggestions.